# Backlinks from old domain

Tags: seo, backlinks, disavow-links

My clients have a eCommerce store that sold a variety of vapour accessories/e-liquid stuff intended for wholesale(olddomain.com) and that did not work out for them. So they re-branded and are now just selling e-liquids to consumers(newdomain.com).

When looking at webmaster i can see over 12000 back-links from olddomain.com to the new one. would these links get classed as unnatural? Would/should I disavow these links?

Comment: I would be concerned and check out why there are so many links. If in the header, footer, or sidebar, I would consider removing them and creating more natural links to the site. Otherwise, if there are 12k links within content, I would bet that G will see them as spam. Cheers!!

Comment: That is what i was worried about, those links have no value to the new site. How would i go about removing the 12000+ links?

Comment: You can use something like Screaming Frog to find the links. Screaming Frog is excellent and will at least give you 500 pages in trial mode. That may be enough to give you and idea of what is going on. If in a template footer, header, sidebar, then I would move it to About or Contact or where ever it makes sense even in content where appropriate. If all 12k are in content, then I would figure out why, could be a plug-in or something, and fix that. If manually done in content, that could be a real chore to fix.

Answer (score 1):

This strongly depends on the quality of the links and where they point to on the site. Therefore, you should:

1. Crawl all links to see if they are potential spam - we use Moz for this to get spam score
2. If the target URLs for these links on olddomain.com are 301 redirected to newdomain.com to preserve link equity, ensure that the redirected page has the same user intent. For example, don't redirect a page selling socks to a page selling earrings.